# Find the position of a unicodechar in a unicodestring

Tags: unicode, lazarus, freepascal

I'm working with Unicode. I want to find the position of a char in a UnicodeString.

For example: the position of `á` in `lùáxõ` is 3.

I have tried several ways, Google'd a lot, read the Lazarus documentation, but still nothing works.

I'm using Lazarus 1.6 and FPC 3.x.

Comment: Surely you use `Pos`

Comment: Use Pos, PosEx, UTF8Pos, UTF16Pos, Fastcode Pos, etc... and not work. Just work after @Marco answer. I can't upvote your comment because of my reputation. thank you

Comment: Pos works fine your code must be defective in some way

Comment: yes, I found it. I add {$codepage utf8} and it works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pos() as David says, but to avoid problems with overloading make sure both arguments are explicitly typed unicode*

E.g. copy and paste this in notepad, and save with **utf-8** encoding

```
{$mode delphi}
{$codepage utf8} // source encoding is utf8, just in case.

var c : unicodechar;
    s : unicodestring;
    i : Integer;
begin
  s:='lùáxõ';
  c:='á'; // or whatever codepoint value of the char is.
  i:=pos(c,s);
  writeln(i);
end.
```

Comment: Yeah, it works after i add {$codepage utf8}. Thank you very much. I just came back to my favorite language Pascal a few days.